# how to destroy excess iodomethane in reaction mixture?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis, safety, halides

I have used iodomethane to make a phenolic $\ce{OH}$ group to $\ce{OMe}$ group in Aq+Methanol medium. I have added water to precipitate the product of mine and will evaporate the solvents but I cant use rotavap until I am sure that any residual iodomethane is not contaminating the condenser of rotavap. How shall I destroy excess iodomethane? will aq. solution of $\ce{KOH}$ work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can destroy small amounts of methyl iodide by hydrolysis with an aqueous solution of sodium hydroxide. You can just add some sodium hydroxide solution to your reaction mixture, if your molecule is stable to basic conditions.

The reaction is: $\ce{NaOH + MeI -> MeOH + NaI}$

From: "A Comprehensive Guide to the Hazardous Properties of Chemical Substances" by Pradyot Patnaik, 2007